# chi squared with zero counts

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, chi-squared-test

Does the chi squared test work if the variables have different levels? Here's an example

```
x <- factor(sample(c('a', 'b', 'c'), 100, replace = T))
y <- factor(ifelse(x == 'a', 'd', 'e'))
```

The contingency table includes zeros:

```
table(x, y)

   y
x    d  e
  a 29  0
  b  0 39
  c  0 32
```

Running  `chisq.test(x, y)` gives a very small p-value, so `x` and `y` are not independent. This is the correct result, but I thought one of the assumptions behind `chisq.test` is that there needs to be no zeros in the contingency table (point 6 [in this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3900058/)).

What's going on here? To me, it looks like `chisq.test` shouldn't work, since not all of the assumptions are met, but the result from the test is correct?

Comment: The paper doesn't say what you say that it says...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, the assumption is about the cells of the **expected** table. None of the cells in your expected table would be 0.

Second, "not working" doesn't mean it won't give a correct answer. When assumptions fail then you lack the full guarantee of the things that have been proven to be true. But you could still get a factually accurate result if you use the method while flouting the assumptions.

That said, the assumption of no zeroes in the expected counts is necessary because of how the chi-square statistic is calculated. If you had actually failed this assumption then running the test would have thrown an error.